# matching 2 arrays in Angular, with matches as checkboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, checkbox

I want to be able to manage User roles in Angular webpage. I have one object which lists all the current roles in the system.

[image]

Then based on the a User, I can get his current role in the role.

[image]

I can list all the roles as checkboxes, then i want to have the user's checkbox selected based on role. E.g. if he is Reporter and Public, I want those checkbox's selected.

```
  <label ng-repeat="m in UserDetails">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="UserDetails[m]" /> {{m}}
  </label>
```

In the `UserDetails` I have all the roles listed. I want the checkboxes selected.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) directive. Maybe something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="UserDetails[m]" 
       ng-checked="currentUsersRoles.indexOf(m) >= 0" /> {{ m }}
```

But to have the user's roles update when the box is checked or unchecked, you may need a slightly different structure.

Let's say your `currentUser`, instead of having an array of roles has a roles property, the value of which in your controller is an object like this:

```
$scope.currentUser.rolesObj = {
  "Public": true,
  "Reporter": false,
  "Partner": false,
  "LCSP": false,
  "Admin": false,
  "StrategicPursuit": false,
  "PA": false
};
```

Then to create your list of checkboxes:

```
<label ng-repeat="(role, value) in currentUser.rolesObj">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value" /> {{ role }}
</label>
```

That should keep your user's roles in sync with the checkboxes. And if you don't have that much control over your user data structure, you could always write a function that builds a currentUser roles object using the existing array:

```
$scope.rolesObjFromArray = function (rolesArr) {
  var rolesObj = {
    "Public": false,
    "Reporter": false,
    "Partner": false,
    "LCSP": false,
    "Admin": false,
    "StrategicPursuit": false,
    "PA": false
  };

  rolesArr.forEach(function (role) {
    rolesObj[role] = true;
  });

  return rolesObj;
}

$scope.currentUser.rolesObj = rolesObjFromArray(currentUserRoles);
```

Here's a [JSFiddle to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/hy0jcs2o/13), in case it helps. Note that the JSFiddle is using Angular 1.2.1, and some tweaking will need to be done if you're using a more recent version.

Comment: This worked out great! How do I get the new values passed back to the User Roles list now? E.g. if i select `admin` how do I get this value added into the `currentUsersRoles`

Comment: You might need to change the structure of your data a little bit. Instead of giving each User an array of roles, you could give each user a roles object with role names for keys and booleans for values. Then you could ngRepeat over the keys to generate the list of checkboxes and then set the values as the ngModel for the checkbox. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: You might need to change the structure of your data a little bit. Instead of giving each User an array of roles, you could give each user a roles object with role names for keys and booleans for values. Then you could ngRepeat over the keys to generate the list of checkboxes and then set the values as the ngModel for the checkbox. I've updated my answer to include this information as well.